# Change Cell color in JQGrid while click on Cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have requirement to change the cell color after click on that. If I click on cell it should become have green color and if I click on same cell it should become red color. Now problem is that I am trying to find how to do it. 
I have tried to use onSelectCell event but whenever I am trying to select any cell it wan’t give me any changes in JQGrid. I have applied onSelectCell on colModel as well as jqGrid level.

I have created static data grid as below,

```
   <html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function()
            {
jQuery("#list4").jqGrid({ datatype: "local", height: 250, 
colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'], 
colModel:[ {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, editable: false, sorttype:"int",
        onSelectCell:function (rowid, celname, value, iRow, iCol) {background: '#888888';}},
 {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date"},
 {name:'name',index:'name', width:100}, 
 {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
 {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"}, 
 {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
 {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false} ],
 multiselect: false,
 caption: "Manipulating Array Data" });
var mydata = [ {id:"1" ,invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}, 
{id:"2",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}, 
{id:"3",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}, 
 ]; 
for(var i=0;i<=mydata.length;i++) jQuery("#list4").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,mydata[i]);

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
Loading Static Grid...
<table id="list4"></table>
<div id="pager3"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do there will not work. According to the documentation of [jQgrid colModel options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options) you will notice that no option is there called `onSelectCell` in colModel. However there is a event called `onCellSelect` in [jqGrid events](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents). It returns the id of the cell and the index of the col, therefore it is now possible to get the `td` that was clicked on. After that all left is to manipulate the css to achieve what is required.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VfLes/28/) example of the functionality. The code there can improved upon a lot, but hopefully it will give and idea of how this can be achieved. The kind of code desribed here will fail if you customize the jqGrid, like giving your own ids to the table instead of jqGrid defaults, so keep an eye for the jqGrid is created. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Thanks to help, your are resolving my first part.

Comment: What is the second part ? You can mark the answer as accepted if it helps you resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

see method SetCell, it allow you to change the cell background.

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods

e.g.

```
$('#grid1').jqGrid('setCell',rowid,cellname,'',{background:'red'});
```

for the clicking behavior, I think you could trap the user's clicks on  onCellSelect or ondblClickRow event.